# Surge Protector Life Span

Tags: ups

I work for a small office that is relocating. Recently all new computers have been purchased for staff. In preparation for the move, I noticed that virtually all the surge protectors in the office seem probably older than 10 years. Is there a surge protector replacement guideline? Should we buy all brand new surge protectors/UPS?

The lights on all of the current surge protectors indicate that working. Earlier this summer there was an explosion at substation a few blocks away, so there could have been a power surge at the office. However it did not seem to impact the computers or surge protectors.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2):

Surge protectors do eventually go bad, this website says to replace after 3-5 years : https://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-surge-protector/

You can also see if there is some sort of brand name on the strip and look it up to see if it has a time limit.

This website also gives some information including that 10 years is too long to go. It mentions that it is hard to know when a surge protector goes bad, so its better to replace them.

https://www.howtogeek.com/212375/why-and-when-you-need-to-replace-your-surge-protector/